# Slack API - how to parse users without notifying

Tags: bots, chatbot, slack, slack-api

Whenever we parse a user by their ID with `<@Usomething>`, it will automatically parse that user ID and replace it with the associated name in channel.

Sometimes you just want to parse the name and not have the person be notified. Is there a way to do a silent parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this by using the Slack API method [users.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info): pass the user ID into that method, retrieve the user's `name` attribute, and then use that in your Slack message.

Comment: I should've provided more context, I didn't want to make another http request to get this information. Although I ended up getting the entire list of users and caching in-memory until I need to get a user's details